# Solution to rewrite path on old software to prevent write permission inside %programfiles%

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a solution to rewrite specific path an old software use inside it's own folder, in %programfiles%.

Old software saving it's data in it's own folder require editing permission (reducing security) or giving administrative privilege to the end user (the end user will break the system).

Is there a solution to hook and rewrite specific path a software may want to read/write on, from "%programfiles%\$SoftwareName\$SaveFolder" to "%userprofile%\Documents\$SoftwareName\$SaveFolder" that doesn't require administrative privileges for the end user ?

Note that %userprofile% should always link to current user's profile and not to one specific user folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes what you're asking is possible. You could write a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540382(v=vs.85).aspx) for this. One of the things that file system filter drivers are capable of is intercepting every read and write to a file system, examine the operation for certain path names, and redirecting the operation to a different path name. This is what Windows Vista and above use to do file and folder redirection for "UAC file virtualization" - that thing where applications that try to write to protected system folders automatically get redirected to AppData and the like. If you issue a `fltmc` command to view currently installed filter drivers on your system, you will likely see `luafv` listed. (UAC was originally called LUA) and the FV stands for File Virtualization.

It is not a trivial task though, unless kernel programming and driver writing just comes naturally to you.

In fact, now that I think about it... UAC file virtualization should already be handling this for you. This is exactly what it was designed to do - make applications that were attempting to write to Program Files or HKLM, write to to User AppData or HKCU instead. A deeper inspection of your application and system is needed I think to determine why it is avoiding UAC virtualization.

Another solution that you will probably find much easier, would be to create an [application compatibility shim](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/10/15/using-the-correctfilepaths-shim-to-redirect-files-on-windows-vista.aspx). I think this approach is highly preferable to the file system filter driver.

An AppCompat shim is capable of customized file and folder redirection. I would say this is much preferable because it's much easier, and it only targets your unruly application, instead of having to make a system wide modification by installing a driver.

Comment: Thanks for the docs, software i wish to correct doesn't benefit from UAC redirection it seems, as the software just fails silently (doing as it was saved but nothing was saved) or throw permission errors. Some are not installed on default path as they are on a network drive, too. The driver path is clearly hardcore for me but the application compatibility shim looks awesome. As a bonus, your link also helped me to understand how our real time defrag software works, they wrote a nice filter, listed in fltmc.

Comment: Some feedback, your solution is almost perfect, only downside is, it seems Microsoft doesn't like relative path...